Publishing two versions at the same time in Google Play Store
I'm trying to publish a new bundle of my app on the Google Play Store.
I had uploaded build A with full rollout by mistake, then later on I uploaded build (same code but incremented version) B with staged rollout at 2%.
As far as I understand, I cannot remove the first bundle from publishing overview, but what would happen If I pubish the two builds here? Both of them will get published? Or just the last one?
I contacted google play support without success, I dont want to publish any version with full rollout because its a critical build but I just have the option to send the two builds at the same time.
I'm stuck at this point without being able to publish anything because of that full rollout pending.


I had uploaded build A with full rollout by mistake, then later on I uploaded build (same code but incremented version) B with staged rollout at 2%. As far as I understand, I cannot remove the first bundle from publishing overview, but what would happen If I pubish the two builds here? Both of them will get published? Or just the last one?

Per my understanding of how Google Play works:
A will be deployed to 100% of the users. This means all of your users will have at least this version available to them. "At least" because ...
B will be deployed to 2% of the users. This means 2% of the user base will have this version available to them. The remaining 98% will have A available to update to.

I contacted google play support without success,

lol - google play "support" - good one

I dont want to publish any version with full rollout because its a critical build but I just have the option to send the two builds at the same time.


Im stuck at this point without being able to publish anything because of that full rollout pending.

You're best bet at this point, I think, is to checkout the commit from your revision control system that was the basis for the version you originally had published, bump the version number, rebuild, and redeploy yet another release that will override the others.
Good Luck.
